# Does Huey Lewis & the News exist in the Back to the Future universe?

Tags: back-to-the-future

In the first movie, Marty performs a version of Power of Love before he is told (by Huey Lewis in a cameo, no less) that he is simply "too loud." Was Marty just performing a cover, or did *he* write the song in the BTTF universe?

Comment: Perhaps this would be better suited in the Movies/TV Stack?

Comment: I don't know about "Power of Love", but Marty _did_ write "Johnny B. Goode".

Comment: @CthulhuCarl **Wrong!!** I heard that Calvin Klein invented "Johnny B. Goode". He wrote the main riff the same day he was nearly hit by a train walking on the bridge over *Eastwood Ravine*

Comment: I'm pretty sure the exact quote is "too darn loud", which somehow is a lot funnier. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lt2BN9SeZsc

Comment: Marty's bedroom has a poster of Huey Lewis' album "Sports" on the wall.

Comment: And I just saw the answer which mentions the poster.  Oh well.

Answer (score 23):

Huey Lewis and the News absolutely exists in the BTTF universe.

A poster for the band's album entitled "Sports" can be seen on the wall of Marty McFly's bedroom in BTTF, specifically in the scene where he wakes up after having returned to 1985, saying "What a nightmare!".

[image: Huey Lewis & the News - Sports, BTTF]
[image: Huey Lewis & the News - Sports, album cover]

Marty is actually awakened by a clock radio that plays "Back in Time", also by Huey Lewis and the News, although it was not released on any Huey Lewis and the News albums or as a single, it is on the BTTF soundtrack.

Also, at the end of BTTF 3, when Marty is about to be challenged to a drag race by Needles in front of the Hilldale housing development, the radio in Needles' truck is clearly playing "Power of Love" and is [diegetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diegesis#Film_sound_and_music) ($5 word of the day), so the characters are aware of it.

And it gets even better:  The lyrics to "Back In Time" actually include the words ***[Get back, Marty](http://www.metrolyrics.com/back-in-time-lyrics-huey-lewis-the-news.html)*** (about 2:58 into the 4:18 version of the song)...  so Marty actually hears Huey Lewis refer to him by name!  This part of the song isn't played during this scene, but depending on how much of it he listened to, he could have heard it.

Comment: Meaning the *Back to the Future* soundtrack exists in the *Back to the Future* universe... oh god...

Comment: Great catch, never noticed that before.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Paradox!

Comment: Tommy Westphall is eating his own legs.

Comment: So that means that in universe Marty was actually told that he was too loud by... Huey Lewis?

Comment: @Michael Well, sort of.  It is Huey Lewis, but IMDB lists him as "High School Band Audition Judge" although uncredited.

Answer (score 9):

Don't remember the particular song at the moment, but Huey Lewis & the News is playing on the radio in the truck at the end of the third movie. So I'd say yes.

Comment: The Power of Love.

Comment: New head canon: that's not Huey Lewis, it's Marty and his band, famous musicians in the post-part-one timeline.

Comment: Having watched the 2015 re-release, I also saw the Huey Lewis poster for the first time. Based on that alone, @iwantmyphd's answer is the best, IMO.